# nohup only redirecting errors to a log file

Tags: bash, unix, nohup

I'm using a script file to start processes in background in unix. The processes that I'm triggering with this file are .netCore apps and they have their own logs but sometimes I need to capture unhandled exceptions so I'd like to redirect only the errors to a log file when these type of things happen.

This is my script code:

```
cd $1
chmod +x $2
nohup ./$2 >error`date +%Y%m%d`.log &
```

Where the first parameter that the script receives is the folder in which the app to start is located and the second parameter is the app executable file.

So far I've been able to redirect not only the errors but also any outputs. Is there a way to only redirect the errors to that log file?

Answer (score 0):

```
 2>error`date +%Y%m%d`.log &
```

will redirect stderr

```
1>output
```

will redirect stdout

Comment: The following would be the line, right?

nohup ./$2 2>error`date +%Y%m%d`.log &

What if also I'd like to avoid having the output messages?

Comment: @RodrigoBengoechea: `nohup ./$2 2>error$(date +%Y%m%d).log &`

Comment: thanks @Cyrus! that worked, I also like to redirect stdout to /dev/null so those messages will be not seen. How can I do that?

Comment: Replace `&` with `>/dev/null &`. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams